# kivy: make widget react different for single- and double-tap

Tags: python, kivy

I detect a double-tap on a widget like described in the kivy doc.
How can i realize different reaction for single- and double-tap in a good way?

```py
def on_touch_down(self, touch):
    if self.collide_point(*touch.pos):
        if touch.is_double_tap:
            print('here start function B (but not function A in advance!)')
        else:
            print('here start function A')
    return super(MyLabel, self).on_touch_down(touch)
```

Comment: I am currently facing the same issue. Have you found a solution to your problem? Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

I would check this out: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/kivy-users/slYzx9uZ39M
it looks like you can set a tap wait period where it waits to see if you are going to tap again after the first tap. Hope this helps. Wish I knew more :P