# Python 3 & Kivy: React only to double tap "not" single tap

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, single-vs-double-tap

I hope you are all doing well in these strange times.

I have a question that has been asked before [4 years](https://www.reddit.com/r/kivy/comments/3xr67s/separate_actions_of_single_and_double_tap/) and [6 years ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25429156/kivy-make-widget-react-different-for-single-and-double-tap), but neither answer in the thread works (at least for me), so in the hope that there has been some progress in the last years, I have to ask again.

When using Python 3.8.2 and Kivy 2.0.0 and running the below code (working snippet on my machine), on double-clicking/double-tapping the widget, both the single tap and the double tap registers.

How can I write this code in a way that only the single or only the double tap is registered? I just don't want both at the same time (I am actually not sure, why the out-of-the-box behaviour is desirable...)

In case it is important, I am on Windows 10 using anaconda, but I will port this code later to Raspbian.

Thanks a lot, folks. Really appreciate your input and stay healthy all of you :)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import kivy
kivy.require('2.0.0')

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout

class RootWidget(BoxLayout):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(RootWidget, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        if touch.is_double_tap:
            print("Double Hello!")
        else:
            print("Single Hello!")

class TestApp(App):

    def build(self):
        root = RootWidget()
        return root


if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

Comment: When you receive a single tap, schedule your single tap function to occur in X seconds. If you receive a double tap within that period, unschedule the single tap function and immediately run the double tap function instead.

Comment: @inclement: Thanks for the pointer. Do you maybe have a code snippet that I could work with? Thanks :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this:

```
scheduled_event = None
def on_touch_down(self, touch):
    if self.scheduled_event is not None:
            self.scheduled_event.cancel()
            self.scheduled_event = None
    if touch.is_double_tap:
            do_your_double_tap_thing()
    else:
        double_tap_wait_s = 1
        self.scheduled_event = Clock.schedule_once(do_your_single_tap_thing, double_tap_wait_s)
```

Comment: I wouldn't have come up with that in a million years :-( Thank you very much, @inclement. Little addendum for those who may struggle with a TypeError on positional arguments. "def do_your_single_tap_thing(self, *args):" is the answer. I kept on leaving the *args bit out...